# .mov format support in flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Which version of .mov file is supported by flex 3 ?

[Scenario :- I have created custom audio player and trying to play .mov file,but some of them are playing and some not]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can ony play the .mov files that have video encoded with H263 encoder and have audio encoded as aac. As long as you have such encoding in mov file you can play them otherwise not. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew; Flex didn't support .mov files.  You'll have to convert that .mov file to an flv file for use within the Flash Player.

Comment: thank you, but I tried with some mov files and I got success and If I want to convert it through program,If you know , can you please tell me?  thank you

Comment: I know that ffmpeg is a common, free, command line conversion program.  http://www.ffmpeg.org/